# How to Disable jquery fsscroll in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My problem is that when I go in the mobile view, scrolling is not free. My page has no problem in displaying the desktop and the scrolling is in three sections(as you can see), but I want the scrolling to be free in the mobile view, that means i dont want it to be in three sections

```js
  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    var win = $(this);
    if (win.width() >= 768) { 
    $( "#main" ).attr( "data-fs-scroll" );
    $( "#link" ).attr( "href" );
    $( "#script" ).attr( "src" );
    $("#main").addClass('main');
   }
    else{
      $("#main").removeClass('main');
      $( "#main" ).removeAttr( "data-fs-scroll" );
      $( "#link" ).removeAttr( "href" );
      $( "#script" ).removeAttr( "src" );
    }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/img/logo.png">
  <link id="link" rel="stylesheet" href="one-page-scroll-fsscroll/src/jquery.fsscroll.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script id="script" src="one-page-scroll-fsscroll/src/jquery.fsscroll.min.js"></script>
  <title>Tiger</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" class="main" data-fs-scroll>
    <div class="sections" id="section">
      <div class="section section0">
      </div>
            <div class="section section1">
      </div>
            <div class="section section2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(window.innerWidth < 767) {
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
    var win = $(this);
    if (win.width() >= 768) { 
    $( "#main" ).attr( "data-fs-scroll" );
    $( "#link" ).attr( "href" );
    $( "#script" ).attr( "src" );
    $("#main").addClass('main');
   }
    else{
      $("#main").removeClass('main');
      $( "#main" ).removeAttr( "data-fs-scroll" );
      $( "#link" ).removeAttr( "href" );
      $( "#script" ).removeAttr( "src" );
    }
});
```